# StoryBoard上で、親Viewに対するサイズ比率を設定した上で、最大値を設定する方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, autolayout

Xcodeのストーリーボードでメールアドレス登録フォームのレイアウトを組んでいます。
iPhone、iPad対応のレスポンシブデザインにしていきたいのですが、下記内容が実現できません。

■  実現したい事

- UITextFieldのwidthは親Viewの80%とする ←iPhone用
- UITextFieldのwidthの最大値は400ポイントとする ←iPad用

といった設定を行いたいです。
iPhoneでの表示は、横幅ほぼ一杯までUITextFieldを広げるが
iPadでの表示の際は横幅を400ポイントを最大値とするレイアウトにしたいと考えております。

■  質問内容
UITextFieldのwidthは親Viewの80%とする為に
Equal Widths ConstraintでMultiplier 0.8で設定した上で、
widthの最大値を設定するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

[image: 現在の設定]

コードで実行時に画面サイズを取得した上で分岐を書く以外に
ストーリーボード上で上記設定を行う方法はあるのでしょうか？

アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 後は普通にUITextFieldに最大幅の制約を追加すれば良いだけのように思えるのですが、それでは何か問題なのでしょうか?それともXcode上で最大幅制約を追加するやり方がわからないと言うご質問でしょうか?

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。わかりにくい質問内容で申し訳ありません...。UITextFieldのwidthは親Viewの80%とした上で、最大幅制約を追加する方法がわからない状態です。同一のオブジェクトに対して複数のwidthの制約を設定する事は出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: 単純な最大幅の制約と親ビューなどに対する幅制約とは異なる形になります。親ビューに対する幅制約とは別に最大幅制約をつけることができますが?

Comment: ありがとうございます。 "親ビューに対する幅制約とは別に最大幅制約をつけること" これがまさに私の今、実現したい事です。こちらのやり方をご教授いただけると大変助かります...。

Comment: こちら自身で調査しきらずに、質問する事は失礼でした。大変申し訳ございません。まず"親ビューに対する幅制約とは別に最大幅制約をつける方法"をネット上で検索するなど探してみます。もし解決出来なかった際には、再度質問させていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 別に失礼だとは思わないんですが、最大幅の指定の方が大抵の人には簡単なので、確認させてもらいたかっただけなのですが。最大幅の指定の仕方がわからないと言うことであれば、ご質問内容を編集していただければと思います。

Comment: 解決できたのならばよかったです。1点注意事項ですが、両方の幅制約が矛盾する場合に、変なことが起こらないようPriorityの値を「最大幅が400」＞「親の0.8倍」となるようにしてください。

Comment: こちら解決致しました。

幅の制約を複数設定する事が出来ないと思っておりましたが
 OOPer様のおっしゃる通り、親ビューに対する幅制約とは別に最大幅制約をつけることができました。
 Attributes InspectorでRelationをLess Than or Equalに設定した上でConstantに制約を追加。
その上でPriorityで、制約の優先度を調整する。といった流れで実現出来ました。

前回の質問に続き、ご親切に本当にありがとうございました。
こちらの内容も、回答として投稿したいと思います。

Comment: まさにおっしゃる通りです！ありがとうございます！Priorityの概念が理解出来ていなかった為に、同じオブジェクトに複数の幅制約を追加する事が出来ないと勘違いしておりました。本当にご親切にありがとうございました。

Comment: こちらも制約の付け方ではつい最近まで自分でも悩んでいたのに、問題点をうまく汲み取れずに失礼しました。ご回答の方は是非よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決致しました。

一つのオブジェクトに対して、widthの制約を複数つける事が出来ないと思っておりましたが、下記手順で実現出来ました。

1. 最大幅(Less Than or Equal)を400に設定
2. 親Viewの0.8倍の幅に設定
3. Priorityの値を「最大幅400」 ＞ 「親Viewの0.8倍」に設定

Priorityの概念が理解出来ていなかった為に、同じオブジェクトに複数の幅制約を追加する事が出来ないとものと思っておりましたが、いただきましたアドバイスのお陰で実現する事が出来ました。
ありがとうございました。